# "Life before baby" doesn't fit in here; but is pretty important itself

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

Questions about maternity insurance, what to expect during pregnancy, how to get pregnant (yes, that is a serious question), and other worries/questions that expecting or soon-to-be expecting couples have don't really fall under the "parenting" category; they're more-or-less fall under "pre-parenting."

Many of the answers to the questions above would also be highly subjective - and wouldn't fit in with the Stack Exchange model at all.

The Parenting.SE target-audience are the foremost expert in these areas as they have mostly recently experienced it (I'd argue that they are, collectively, more of an "expert" than the experts/doctors in these *opinionated* matters).

So, what should a pre-parent do? Where should they go to find <strike>answers</strike> opinions on these very important questions. Should these types of questions be allowed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There were several parent-related proposals that were merged in support of a unified Parenting site. Since topics like [Pregnancy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30830/pregnancy) and Adoption were folded into this subject, **those subject are on topic for this site.**

As for "pregnancy questions" being too subjective, it's no more or less so than parenting in general. As long as you have a specific question that can be reasonably answered (i.e. follow the principles of [**Good Subjective, Bad Subjective**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)), the subject will be fine.

If users stick to specific questions about problems they actually have, this site will do well. But there are a lot of overly-broad, generalized discussions along the lines of  *"What do you think about <controversial topic>?"*. Those will have to be closed as [not a real question]. While they may be entertaining and fun, they're simply not well-suited to this type of Q&A and not what this site is about.

Comment: While pregnancy questions can work as on-topic, and adoption is (IMHO) obviously on-topic, I feel strongly that we should pass on questions about conception.  We simply cannot try to merge every tangentially related subject into the site, especially in this case since [there is already a proposal in the commitment phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-sex-but-were-afraid-to-ask) re: sex and sexual health.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's vitally important we allow 'life before parenthood' as it can help people prepare for parenthood before they arrive there.   This site, for me, is to learn more about parenting and to share what I already do know.  This, for me, also includes letting people know the differences post and pre baby.