# FAQ Index for Parenting Stack Exchange

Tags: support, faq

## Community FAQ

### (For Parenting Stack Exchange)

For official guidance from Stack Exchange, visit the [Help Center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help).

Parenting Stack Exchange is part of a wider network; for issues that apply to Stack Exchange sites in general, see the [FAQ list on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931).

## Asking & Answering

### General

[Policy for voting](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/166)

[Rules and Quality Control vs. a Welcome to the community](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/460)

### Scope/On-Topic: General

[Does Parenting.SE entertain frame-challenge answers? Do we argue the premise of a question?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1413)

[What is our position with questions and answers that push a political viewpoint?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/702)

[Are psychology and sociology based questions about parenting topics on-topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/819)

[Is it acceptable for answers to suggest physical violence?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/619)

### Scope/On-Topic: Medical

[Medical questions: what is the line between on / off topic, and how should they be handled?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/473)

[Are medical discussions allowed on Parenting?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1409)

[Are questions about generic or fundamental medical information on-topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/670)

### Scope/On-Topic: Pregnancy and Family Planning

[Is family planning considered on-topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/135)

["Life before baby" doesn't fit in here; but is pretty important itself](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/67)

### Scope/On-Topic: Questions About Parents

[Are questions regarding adult children/parent relationships on topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1430)

[Manage my parents](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1228)

[Are questions about our relations with parents on topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/957)

### Scope/On-Topic: Product Recommendations

[What is our policy on product suggestions?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/642)

[Asking for product recommendations](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/673)

### Scope/On-Topic: Money and Finance

[Is the "Daycare and Taxes" question appropriate for this site?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/634)

[Is a question about "the best" 529 on topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1419)

### Scope/On-Topic: Who Can Ask

[Can children ask questions here? If not where?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1441)

[What should I do when a user self-identifies as being under 13?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/877)

[Should we allow questions from the child's perspective?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/827)

[Are questions that could be on topic, but asked without a parenting role, still on topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1058)

Comment: This FAQ Index is a follow-up to [this discussion](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1434/33055). It is intended to be a Parenting Stack Exchange equivalent to the [Stack Overflow FAQ Index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/967621).